# Counting ways to place $n$ books on $k$ shelves

Tags: combinatorics

How many ways are there to arrange $n$ books on $k$ shelves assuming the following conditions?

1) The books are *indistinguishable*, the shelves are *distinguishable*

Answer: There are $n$ books and $k-1$ dividers, so this is a sequence of $n+k-1$ stars that we will choose $k-1$ of the stars to turn into dividers, resulting in $n$ stars representing books and $k-1$ dividers. The answer is:

$$n+k-1 \choose k-1$$

2) The books are *indistinguishable*, the shelves are *indistinguishable*

Answer: This is just the number of ways in case 1 divide by k! because case 1 counted distinguishable shelves, which implicitly counted the permutation of the shelves. So we explicit divide by the permutation of the shelves for indistinguishable shelves. The answer is:

$$\frac{n+k-1 \choose k-1}{k!}$$

3) the books are *distinguishable*, the shelves are *distinguishable*, and the order of the books on each shelf matters

Answer: do this 2 stages. First, there are $n!$ ways of arranging the books. Then, for each arrangement, use the stars and dividers method in case 1 to place $k-1$ dividers, which there are $n+k-1 \choose k-1$ ways. The anwser is:

$$n! \times {n+k-1 \choose k-1}$$

4) the books are *distinguishable*, the shelves are *indistinguishable*, and the order of the books on each shelf matters

Answer: this is just like the relationship between case 1 and case 2, so we divide by the result from case 3 by $k!$. The answer is:
$$\frac{n! \times {n+k-1 \choose k-1}}{k!} $$

Is my logic correct in these answers?

Comment: Read about the [twelvefold-way](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twelvefold_way).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Case 1 and 3 are correct but the rest aren't.

Note when $n=1$ and $k = 3$ your answer for 2 gives:

$$
\frac{\binom{3}{2}}{3!} = \frac{1}{2}
$$

This should tell you that something is wrong. (Hint permutations don't act freely on your objects from Case 1).

Note that some of these questions don't have nice closed forms.

Comment: "*Note that some of these questions don't have nice closed forms*" when limiting yourself to multiplication and addition.  The rest of them are frequent enough that they each do have their own special notation.

Comment: Thanks, I see now that case 2 and case 4 are incorrect, but I think #3 is still correct. Also case 3 is exactly the same as https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1913523/how-many-placements-are-there-of-distinct-books-on-distinct-shelves?rq=1.

Comment: #leontp587 Yes you are right. I had forgotten to take ordering of the books on each shelf into account.